# Actualizar valores en un DF existente con uno nuevo

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un archivo de excel (Excel 1) el cual tiene datos que deseo actualizar con otro excel (Excel 2). Si el valor de la columna A existe, reemplazar con la nueva. Y si no existe, agregarla.

**Excel 1**

| 0 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | azul | 9.9 | 04/03/2023 |
| 2 | verde | 15.0 | 10/10/2022 |
| 3 | morado | 20.0 | 10/10/2022 |

**Excel 2**

| 0 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | negro | 9.9 | 04/03/2023 |
| 2 | verde | 15.0 | 10/10/2022 |
| 3 | azul | 20.0 | 10/10/2022 |
| 3 | morado | 12.5 | 15/10/2022 |

Después de la ejecución, espero que la lista se actualice de la siguiente manera:

| 0 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | azul | 20.0 | 10/10/2022 |
| 2 | verde | 15.0 | 10/10/2022 |
| 3 | morado | 12.5 | 15/10/2022 |
| 3 | negro | 9.9 | 04/03/2023 |

Hasta el momento, he logrado unir los dos archivos de excel en uno solo, sin embargo no he podido actualizar la columna A con los nuevos datos, solo me lo agrega como otra fila.

Añado el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter


fecha=str(date.today())

cambioPrecio='/Users/Documents/Price/CambioPrecio.xlsx'
masterFile='/Users/Documents/Price/masterFile.xlsx'


df = pd.concat(
    map(pd.read_excel,[cambioPrecio,masterFile]), ignore_index=True
)

writer = ExcelWriter(masterFile)
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet0', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento y los errores que te impiden continuar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Casi lo logras, lo que hace falta es eliminar los duplicados, para eso utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) y la clave está en utilizar el argumento `keep`, por defecto usa `first` pero vamos a utilizar `last`

Y para darle un poco de formato vamos a ordenar el `dataframe` utilizando la columna `A` y volver a generar los índices para que inicien desde cero

Ejemplo completo utilizando tus datos desde los archivos "sample1.xlsx" y sample2.xslx":

```
import pandas as pd

cambioPrecio='sample1.xlsx'
masterFile='sample2.xlsx'


df = pd.concat(
    map(pd.read_excel,[cambioPrecio,masterFile]), ignore_index=True
).drop_duplicates(['A'], keep='last').sort_values('A').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
        A     B           C
0    azul  20.0  10/10/2022
1  morado  12.5  15/10/2022
2   negro   9.9  04/03/2023
3   verde  15.0  10/10/2022
```

Lo único que haría falta es utilizar  `ExcelWriter` pero esa parte ya te funciona correctamente y por eso la omití.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Esto ha sido mi salvación! Ha funcionado perfectamente

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!