# Full outer join de dos dataframes sin agregar sufijos

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, dataframe

Estaba intentando hacer un full outer join de dos dataframes en python pero no sé cómo hacer para que las columnas se unan bien sin necesidad de que se les agregue un sufijo.

Me explico, este es mi primer dataframe (df1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi segundo dataframe  (df2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea que tengo es que unirlos y obtener un resultado similar a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, implementando el siguiente código, no funciona, python empieza a crear un sufijo x para la primera tabla y un sufijo y para la segunda, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi código en python:

```
    import pandas as pd

    df1 = pd.read_excel('prueba_dataframes_DF1andDF2.xlsx',sheet_name='DF1')

    df2 = pd.read_excel('prueba_dataframes_DF1andDF2.xlsx',sheet_name='DF2')

    df_sol = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on='ID')
```

El archivo prueba_dataframes_DF1andDF2.xlsx es el que contiene los dataframes

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Actualizar valores en un DF existente con uno nuevo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/553637/actualizar-valores-en-un-df-existente-con-uno-nuevo)